# Wordpress Database connection from FPDF

Tags: wordpress, fpdf

I'm using a tuto to build a little plugin to print result from a database into pdf.
I used FPDF library to do it.

Now I juste want to print the user name into my pdf. But it seems not working for me... Here is the problem : 
"Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()"

And here is my code :

```
     <?php

           if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
            exit;
        }

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) { include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); } 


        include( 'atomicsmash-pdf-helper-functions.php');


        if( isset($_POST['generate_posts_pdf'])){
            output_pdf();
        }

        function output_pdf() {
          global $wpdb;
          $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
              $pdf = new PDF_HTML();
              $pdf->AddPage();
              $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
              $pdf->Cell(40,10, $current_user->display_name);
              $pdf->Cell(0,5,'L NAME:'.$current_user['display_name'], 0, 0, 'L');
              $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'Hello World');


            $pdf->Output('D','resultat.pdf');
            exit;
        }


        function as_fpdf_create_admin_page() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <form method="post" id="as-fdpf-form">
                  <button class="button button-primary" type="submit" name="generate_posts_pdf" value="generate">Generate PDF from Wordpress Posts</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
```

It seems as if I'm not connected to wpdb...

If someone can help me I'll be extremely thanksfull !

See you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You need to include wp-load.php

Which is Bootstrap file for setting the ABSPATH constant and loading the wp-config.php file. The wp-config.php file will then load the wp-settings.php file, which will then set up the WordPress environment.

If you are in plugin folder then you need to include like:

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Yagnesh. But i've this message now : 
Warning: require_once(../../../wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...

Comment: @Clémentine can you please see where locate wp-load.php in your wordpress project and set that path so this error will not come.

Comment: I tried different ways, this one doesn't return an error with wp-load: <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');?>   But I always find the error from the beginning: call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

Comment: This should fix your problem. Please include after wp-load.php   <?php
if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) {
    include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); 
}
?>

Comment: Great it's working !!! Thanks a lot Yagnesh. I'll update my code now. Could you just explain what is 'pluggable.php' ? Thanks

Comment: You can know about pluggable.php in detail from this link https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-wordpress-pluggable-functions-and-their-usage--wp-30189